# Post request from angular2 to backend

Tags: angular

I try to send request from frontend(angular2) to backend(ruby, sinatra). 
Now, both of servers is working on one computer(angular on localhost:3001, sinatra on localhost:9292)

I use auth example(http://embed.plnkr.co/TIPmK3/?show=preview), and want to send user data to sinatra.

I see interesting string in `app/_services/authentication.service.ts`:

```
return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {...}
```

But if replace `'/api/authenticate'` on `http://localhost:9292/login` nothing to happen. Request not sended, no errors. Only loading.

Can anyone to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you please provide more detail ?

But as per your question :
Most of the case the issue will be "Cross-Origin Request" ,

So please check if you set headers for that or not like,

I am using Angular in frontend (localhost:3000) and Node(192.168.2.117:4000) in backend , 
we were facing the same issue so we have set headers in node

```
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
   res.setHeader('content-type','application/json');
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Token, Timestamp, X-Requested-With, Language-Code");
```

After that , it's working like charm.

Comment: Thank you for answear. Yes, i set headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*' on backend, but no requests from angular on backend.

Comment: Will you please try to call with

this.http.post('localhost:9292/api/authenticate', ......

Comment: it dont work to. My backend cant take requests on this route, but now, login page is not sleeping after i login click. And has not requests in logs on backend.

Comment: It work if on backend set   headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*' and use example like this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html